# Java count the number of changes in Digits, special characters and letters in a string

Tags: java, string, count

I would like to count the number of changes of digits and special characters and letters in a string, e.g:

```
`215348-jobpoint`
```

contains 3 changes from "8" to special char "-" to letter "j". 
So basically, I am trying to iterate over a char array, and check for the actual and the next char in that array, if the actual and next char are of same Type instance. E.G if they are of same type alphabet (letter) or same instance number, or same type of special chars... How can I do that?

Comment: Sounds to me very similar to the Levenshtein distance algo. See for example here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-levenshtein-distance

Comment: You can create an utility class / method and increase a counter for every time you end up in a different range. Look at this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-check-input-character-alphabet-digit-special-character/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you could accomplish this with a loop and check every time it changes the type increase a counter, I would personally use a [`String#replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) with regex here.

For example:

```
String str = "215348-jobpoint";
System.out.println("Input: \"" + str + "\"");

// Replace chunks of digits with a single '0':
str = str.replaceAll("\\d+", "0");
System.out.println("After replacing digit chunks: \"" + str + "\"");

// Replace chunks of letters with a single 'A':
str = str.replaceAll("[A-Za-z]+", "A");
System.out.println("After replacing letter chunks: \"" + str + "\"");

// Replace chunks of non-digits and non-letters with a single '~':
str = str.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z\\d]+", "~");
System.out.println("After replacing non-digit/non-letter chunks: \"" + str + "\"");

// Since we transformed every chunk of subsequent characters of the same type to a single character,
// retrieving the length-1 will get our amount of type-changes
int amountOfTypeChunks = str.length();
int amountOfTypeChanges = amountOfTypeChunks -1;
System.out.println("Result (amount of chunks of different types): " + amountOfTypeChunks);
System.out.println("Result (amount of type changes): " + amountOfTypeChanges);
```

Resulting in:

```
Input: "215348-jobpoint"
After replacing digit chunks: "0-jobpoint"
After replacing letter chunks: "0-A"
After replacing non-digit/non-letter chunks: "0~A"
Result (amount of chunks of different types): 3
Result (amount of type changes): 2
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##nZNPT9tAEMXv@RSjveAoOCEtlaqgHqyeOFSVoKcSkDb22Nmw3jX7Jyit4KuH2V2XVApBTS@27Jl583tv7RVf83xV3W@3peTWwjcu1O8BQOcXUpRgHXd0W2tRQUul7NoZoZqbW@DD0AaQXlCjgS/APkw/fTz/nK/0otNCOXaRejbWYTvW3o076nZSZexSdd7NYM4YjOL0CBg9DC8GcWQygSvsJC8RyqVX9xZ0DZVohLPwKNwSOFjaKxFOzk5mcSQh0HVs0mQhZcbm82rEToGdBelDMEXt0EAaC27ion7xkYwSHWntQRbvQt4U@U@e/7qNpMUxpGnd/6EqrfI@Uq6q@HiA/vl9@ruET1EnB8/HOHilmOwA/sXPtVDk5hHBGa5srU2LFeAazSZNB4fWLyw@eFThMLnhZTRHBbdEsLyl4U1HF73z@tp3@meRQfrEcR1Yw5hE1bhlPqWMpIQGHWhvgLfa05YgTYo5qagGbZQg3335e/2Dil/TAaQck1rW57XfGmWo9w2BfHo45Cu0XjrIdlh//0V1jSZkElDtcAYh4/0Fw2PkY4696zcVUyVIPg2ettsX)

Note that your example input `"215348-jobpoint"` has two type changes: from `215348` to `-`, and from `-` to `jobpoint`, instead of the three you stated. If you are regardless looking for the output `3`, so are looking for the amount of type-chunks instead of amount of type changes, you can remove the `-1` after the `str.length()` (in which case an input like `"abc"` would result in `1` instead of `0`). I've added both results in the code above.

Also, the `0`, `A`, and `~` I've used can be any other character. Since we only want to know the length of the resulting String after the replacements, which character it is is irrelevant (although don't use a letter as replacement for the digits of course).

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps 
Take String array of size three.Keep all special chars in one position, all numbers in one and letters in one
like arr = {"01...9","!....@","a....z"}
now check each char if it contained in different position in arr, then increase the count.
You can save the position of the previous char.

```
if(!arr[previousKey].contains(character))
{
    count++;
    change previousKey to position which contain the character
}
else
    continue;
```